# creating objectquery

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have an ef model and i want to "query" it using objectquery. So far i create my objectquery like this:

```
myQuery = new ObjectQuery<T>(mergeOption, context)
```

Is it possible to create an objectquery without the specifying the context right from the start (set it later on)? In my application i have multiple threads that needs to get the base query, extend and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function, not a var:

```
protected ObjectQuery<T> myQuery(MyObjectContext context, MergeOption mergeOption)
{
     return new ObjectQuery<T>(mergeOption, context);
}
```